# Should token store into database in Ruby On Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I use the gem `jwt`、`devise` to build a user login system,

I generate a model Authentication to check the token exist or not.

follow this code:

models/authentication.rb

```
class Authentication < ApplicationRecord
  def self.generate_access_token(email)
    payload = {:email => email}
    secret = 'secret'
    token = JWT.encode payload, secret, 'HS256'
    return token
  end
end
```

controllers/user/sessions_controller.rb

```
def create
    user = User.where(email: params[:email]).first
    if user&.valid_password?(params[:password])
      @token = Authentication.generate_access_token(user.email)
      Authentication.create(access_token: @token)
      authentications = {token: @token, email: user.email}
      render json: authentications, status: :created
    else
      head(:unauthorized)
    end
  end
```

when I do a post request to `user/sessions` I will get token and user email and store it in localstorage of client, and help me to check the token is valid.

follow this code:

```
def authenticate_token
  token = Authentication.find_by_access_token(params[:token])
  head :unauthorized unless token
end
```

In my question, are there ways to let token don't need to store into database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can decode the token and get the email stored in it, and find user by that email.

Suppose you carry the token in the `Authorization` header, like

```
Authorization: Bearer <token>
```

then you can define a `before_action` to do this:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::API
  before_action :authenticate_token

  def authenticate_token
    token = request.headers['Authorization'].to_s =~ /^Bearer (.*)$/i && $1
    return head :unauthorized unless token
    payload = JWT.decode(token, 'secret', true, algorithm: 'HS256')
    user = User.find_by(email: payload['email'])
    return head :unauthorized unless user
    # TODO set the `user` as current_user
    # How to patch devise's `current_user` helper is another story
  end
end
```

If I were you, I would put user ID in the token, not email, because ID is shorter, and faster to lookup from database, and it exposes nothing personal to the internet (note that JWT is not encrypted. It's just signed).

Or you can skip all these messy things by just using [knock](https://github.com/nsarno/knock) instead of `devise`.